# How to create a directory in %appdata%

Tags: c#, directory

I want to make a directory within the %appdata% folder. This is what I have so far:

```
public MainForm() {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"%appdata%\ExampleDirectory");
}
```

This does not work, but it also doesn't crash or show any errors of any kind. How would I go about doing this? I have done research, and it does work if I use the actual path:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\ExampleDirectory");
```

However, it does not work when I use the %appdata%. This is problematic as I don't know the usernames of the people using the program, so I can't use the full path.

I have also tried this:

```
var appdata = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
var Example = Path.Combine(appdata, @"\Example");
Directory.CreateDirectory(Example);
```

And it also does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create appdata folder with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500080/how-to-create-appdata-folder-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

// Combine the base folder with your specific folder....
string specificFolder = Path.Combine(folder, "YourSpecificFolder");

// Check if folder exists and if not, create it
if(!Directory.Exists(specificFolder)) 
    Directory.CreateDirectory(specificFolder);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
string example = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%AppData%\Example");
Directory.CreateDirectory(example);
```

`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables()` will replace the environment variable `AppData` with its value, usually `C:\Users\<Username>\Appdata\Roaming`.

To get a list of your environment variables, run the `set` command with no arguments from the command line.

Comment: Can u please provide more information about the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Environment.GetFolderPath()` and `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`:

```
string appDatafolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
string folder = Path.Combine(appDatafolder, "ExampleDirectory");
Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
```

This will create the folder under `C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming`.

Using `SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` will use `AppData\Local` instead.

To get `AppData` only use:

```
string appDatafolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)));
```

See [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Environment.GetFolderPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN for more information

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
 var appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
var path = Path.Combine(appData, @"\ExampleDirectory");
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Comment: How about this  `string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "ExampleDirectory");
if(!Directory.Exists(path)) 
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);`